# How to add multiple inputs for parent-child models in a rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a very simple question.

I have a form in my rails application, in which I want the user to fill in some stuff for multiple items.

More specifically, I have an array like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, title: 'foo'},
  {id: 2, title: 'bar'}, 
  {id: 3, title: 'baz'}
]
```

For each item, the user needs to specify an amount. So the data that I would like to get eventually should look like this:

```
{ 
  # other fields...
  items: [
    {id: 1, amount: 4}
    {id: 2, amount: 2}
    {id: 3, amount: 7}
}
```

So, there should be three inputs in the form that allow the user to specify this. What would this look like in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough example:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @foo = Foo.new
    3.times { @foo.items.build }
  end

  def create
    params[:items].each do |item|
      Foo.create(item)
    end
  end
end

<%= form_tag foo_path do %>
  <% @foo.each do |bar| %> 
    <%= fields_for "items[#{bar.id}]", bar do |b| %>
      <%= b.text_field :amount %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```